# Add "S" prefix to values when meeting dropdown condition

Tags: html, mysql, sql

I wish to add a "S" prefix(without quotes) to my $tranid, if user select "SH" from the dropdown list.

So it will become S$tranid, so it will become S000001

i was trying concat previously but seems like i mess up and it doesnt work at all.

@This is my strsql query

```
/** Start To Save New record **/
if($action == "SAVE_DATA")
{ 
  if($tranid == "")
  {
    $strSQL = "select cs.getInvNo('SH') as tranid; ";
    $result = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("sql error in retrieving trans id.");
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $tranid = $row['tranid'];
    }
  }


  $strSQL = "insert into cs.cs_inv_header(inv_no,inv_date,inv_so,inv_bill_to,inv_ship_to,inv_loc,";
  $strSQL .="inv_cust_code,inv_po,inv_term,inv_curr,inv_ship_via,inv_status,inv_cby,inv_cdate) ";
  $strSQL .= "values('$tranid','$shipDate','$so','$custNo','$shipTo','$loc','$custNo','$ref',";
  $strSQL .= "'$term','$curr','$shipVia','Y','".$_SESSION['SYS_CS']['USER_ID']."',now());";
  mysql_query($strSQL,$link) or die ("sql error on inserting cs.cs_inv_header.");
  unset ($strSQL);

  $strSQL = "insert into cs.cs_inv_det(invd_no,invd_part,invd_desc,invd_qty,invd_uom,invd_cost,";
  $strSQL .="invd_total,invd_vend_part,invd_rmk_ori,invd_rmk,invd_cby,invd_cdate) ";
  $strSQL .= "values('$tranid','$part','$desc',$qty,'$uom',$cost,$total,'$custPart','$rmk',";
  $strSQL .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($rmk)."','".$_SESSION['SYS_CS']['USER_ID']."',now());";
  mysql_query($strSQL,$link) or die ("sql error on inserting cs.cs_inv_det.");
  unset ($strSQL);
  echo "<div class=std align=center>Invoice : $tranid Successfully created...</div>";
  $tranid = "";
  $so = "";
  $custNo = "";
  $term = "";
  $ref = "";
  $shipVia = "DDP";
  $curr = "";
  $part = "";
  $uom = "";
  $cost = "";
  $qty = "";
  $total = "";
  $desc = "";
  $rmk = "";
  $loc= "";
}
/** End of Saving new record **/
```

@this is my dropdown menu code

```
      <select name="selLoc">
       <option value = "">--Please Select--</option>
       <option value = "HB" <? if($loc=='HB') echo 'selected' ?>>HB-Thailand</option>
       <option value = "HH" <? if($loc=='HH') echo 'selected' ?>>HH-Thailand</option>
       <option value = "MH" <? if($loc=='MH') echo 'selected' ?>>MH-Malaysia</option>
       <option value = "SH" <? if($loc=='SH') echo 'selected' ?>>SH/option>
      </select></td>
```

Comment: Note that this primitive and insecure API was deprecated over a decade ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do like this on the values line

```
$strSQL .="values('S$tranid','$part','$desc',$qty,'$uom',$cost,$total,'$custPart','$rmk',";
```